# RTK Query: Should I use same query for different endpoints if they all have same data structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

On our project we use RTK Query and we have the following situation:

On back wed we have endpoints, for simplicity, `/api/green/cars/`, `/api/blue/cars` and `/api/red/cars` that share the same data structure.

My colleagues couldn't agree whether we should create 3 separate RTK endpoints for them: `getGreenCars`, `getBlueCars`, `getRedCars` with static urls or if we should create one endpoint with a dynamic address:

```
getCars: build.query({
  query: (color) => ({
    url: `/api/${color}/cars`
    method: 'GET'
  })
})
```

Those who favor the one endpoint solution say that it will allow us to avoid code duplication.

Those who favor the multiple endpoints solution say that it will keep our code more clear (one rtk endpoint per one back end endpoint) as well as we will be able to implement tags properly (there will be POST, PUT and DELETE too, so we have to keep that in mind).

We are pretty much in a deadlock so I wonder if anyone knows a good piece of theory about this or has experienced something similar so there is an unambiguous decision for this situation.

Comment: This is subjective at best and not on-topic for Stackoverflow. That said, if you are working with developers on a team that can't follow a simple argument like `color` in your example then you probably don't want them making design decisions or working in the code anyway. The "duplicate" endpoints is not ***DRY*** at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would vote for going with the single function instead of the duplicates with minimal difference.

While it would be easier to extend them if they were separate, you can probably wait until the need arises and refactor out the one(s) that need to be split.

It's how we've approached things in the past, though you have to be open to the future refactor and not try to hold onto the single function to do everything if certain ones require alteration.